# Angular 5 Material - How to set mat-nav-list anchor link to be active on click

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do i set anchor links to be active in my implementation.

**.html**

```
<mat-nav-list class="conversation-list">
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let conversation of conversations">
        <a (click)="goToChat(conversation)">{{getOtherUsers(conversation)}}</a>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>

<div class="chat-box">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
goToChat(conversation) {
    this.router.navigate(['main/chat/', conversation._id]);
}
```

**.routing.module.ts**

```
import { ChatComponent } from './chat.component';
import { ChatDetailComponent } from './chat-detail/chat-detail.component';

const CHAT_ROUTES = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ChatComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: ChatDetailComponent
            }
        ]
    },
];
```

The above code loops over a users conversation and creates a list of users they are chatting with. Each list item is a link to a chat component on the right of the page. When user clicks a link and i want it to be set to active.

Answer (score 29):

The anchor is set to have the class "active" by adding routerLinkActive directive:

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <a mat-list-item routerLinkActive="active">{{link.title}}</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

The problem is there is apparently no styles defined for an active state in the Angular Material package:

angular-material/src/lib/list/_list-theme.scss

angular-material/src/lib/list/list.scss

so an active style has to be defined:

```
.mat-nav-list a.active {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what is done in the docs site, with the classname `docs-component-viewer-sidenav-item-selected`. See https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/main/src/app/pages/component-sidenav/component-nav.html and https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/main/src/app/pages/component-sidenav/_component-sidenav-theme.scss

Answer (score 8):

`routerLinkActive` is a property of `routerLink` so it can only be used alongside the `routerLink` binding.

To style an active link set `routerLink` to the route's path, and set `routerLinkActive` to your own class you will use to indicate 'active'.

For example:

```
<a [routerLink]=`main/chat/'${conversation._id}` 
    routerLinkActive="active-link">{{getOtherUsers(conversation)}}</a>
```

Now use css to target the link:

```
.active-link {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers relied on a custom class. However, `mat-list-item` [has an `activated` input](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatListItem) that we can utilize. We just need to make `mat-list-item` and `routerLinkActive` "talk" to each other. Angular directives are a perfect solution for that.

```
/* eslint-disable @angular-eslint/directive-selector */
import { Directive, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MatListItem } from '@angular/material/list';
import { RouterLinkActive } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[mat-list-item][routerLinkActive]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class RouterActivatedMatListItemDirective implements OnDestroy {
  private subs = new Subscription();

  constructor(matListItem: MatListItem, routerLinkActive: RouterLinkActive) {
    this.subs.add(
      routerLinkActive.isActiveChange.subscribe((isActive) => {
        matListItem.activated = isActive;
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Note how the selector targets both - `mat-list-item` and `routerLinkActive`. This means that we'll have both instances available via dependency injection. Angular is amazing!

This directive is `standalone` so make sure to add it to the imports of the component that contains your links or include it in the corresponding module if you use NgModules. No need to change anything else in the template - it just works!

Comment: When the `activated` property is set, it toggles the class `mdc-list-item--activated`, which you would still need to provide a style for.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to use the `.mat-list-item-focus` class to focus the list item:

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <mat-list-item class="mat-list-item-focus">Focused List Item</mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item>Not Focused List Item</mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Answer (score -6):

Try to use something like that :

```
<a [routerLink]="['main/chat/',conversation._id]">{{getOtherUsers(conversation)}}</a>
```

More info about it at https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Comment: I added my router for this module

Comment: <a [routerLink]="[conversation._id]">{{getOtherUsers(conversation)}}</a>
this works, but it does not activate my link? the link is not highlighted

Comment: I tried giving it routerLinkActive="active" but that did not work

Comment: Try
`const CHAT_ROUTES = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ChatComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'main/chat/:id',
                component: ChatDetailComponent
            }
        ]
    },
];`

Comment: OR change your link to 
`<a [routerLink]="['',conversation._id]">{{getOtherUsers(conversation)}}</a>`